# What will be the computational and space complexity if calculate the inverse by using block-inverse matrix method?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Consider a **square** Block matrix

M_block = \begin{bmatrix}
A &B \\ 
 C& D
\end{bmatrix}

where, A, B, C and D are sub-matrices.

I know computational complexity of the above block matrix by general inverse technique would be $O(n^3)$ if size of the above matrix is of $n\times n$.

**Two queries:**

**First:**
What will be the computational  and space complexity if calculate the inverse by using block-inverse matrix method?

**Second:** What will be the computational  and space complexity if calculate the inverse by using block-inverse matrix method and **inverse of $A$ is given**?